# Where clause in OPEN to find unique values

Tags: sas

I am trying to write a macro that will return the number of observations in a dataset, with an option 'where' clause, which will return the number of observations that meet that condition.

I have been using the [OPEN](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n0q72zlfmfjplon1p3nprf85sdin.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) SAS function to do this, like the following example:

```
%macro test(WHERE); 
 %let DSID = %sysfunc(open(sashelp.cars(where=(&WHERE)), i)); 
 %let NOBS = %sysfunc(attrn(&DSID, NLOBSF) ); &NOBS 
 %let RC   = %sysfunc(close(&DSID));
%mend test;

%put %test(WHERE=make='Audi');
```

**Question:**

Is there is a specific `WHERE` clause that will make it return unique values for a specific column (e.g. Make)? Something like the `distinct` ability in `PROC SQL` (I cannot actaully use `PROC SQL` as the output no longer works with `%put`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `where` that will return unique values.

You can use the `doSubL` function to submit step code in a side session.  The side session will not register as step in the calling submit stream.

Example:

```
%macro cars_distinct(var=);
  %local list rc;
  %let rc = %sysfunc(doSubL(%str(
    proc sql noprint; 
      select distinct &var into :list separated by ' '
      from sashelp.cars
    quit;
  )));
  &list.
%mend;

%put %cars_distinct(var=make);
```

Note: `BY` or `CLASS` processing is often a best practice when compared to performing some process (or other macro call) repeatedly as you loop over a distinct list of values.

Comment: thatnk! quick question, what is the RC? I saw it in the original example online, so I kept it in my code but I don't understand what it does

Comment: The `doSubL` function has a return value that needs to be captured.  I've never seen a return value other than zero (`0`).  I would guess the value is non-zero for low-memory (or maybe a security policy setting) situations when the side session is unable to execute.

Comment: this function has solved so many of my problems. I wish I could upvote you twice im so happy now